# SQL Server - reset identity field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a identity column. I need to reset that identity column from zero.
What should i do for this.

Comment: A similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510121/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(<tablename>, RESEED, 0);
```

Comment: The command works in sql server 2014, but you have to put tablename in square brackets ;) : DBCC CHECKIDENT([tablename], RESEED, 0);