# SQL Server delete and increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used this code to create a table which would increment ID by every record:

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees
(
 ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
 NAME varchar (20),
 BALANCE int
)
```

But there is a problem , let's say i want to delete id 6 and after add another record but the new record doesn't take that id 6 but it goes to the next id (7) how can i make it so that if I delete a record all the records after it get a decrement in the ID?

Comment: What's the benefit? I think in the long run this would just make things more difficult.

Comment: Don't rely on identity to keep an incremented value. Normally it will be, but you can easily run into cases where there'll be gabs, even without deleted rows. You should maintain the value yourself. But, I agree with @Elias, what's the benefit? You can always select a row number if you need one without it being persisted.

Comment: You should **NOT** try to do this!! It's a horribly bad idea to "recycle" values that have already been assigned to a row previously! **Don't do this!**

Comment: Can you tell us _why_ you'd like to do this? What are you looking to accomplish by simply having no gaps due to deletes or rolled-back transactions (the other common cause of identity gaps)?

Comment: im doing an app in java which is connected to sql so i can't really select a row...

Comment: well i just wanted to know if i can do this and if it's correct

Comment: Please rethink what do you need. If you are erasing the table just use truncate. By trying to reseed the identity is a real bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practise, but it's possible still.

You could do it like this:

```
declare @max int;  
select @max = coalesce(max(key), 1) from table;
dbcc checkident(table,reseed,@max)
```

Also have a look at this thread:
[Reset AutoIncrement in SQL Server after Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510121/reset-autoincrement-in-sqlserver-after-delete)

Comment: You probably should use something like `select @max = coalesce(max(key), 1) from table;` to avoid issues if the last record was deleted and the table is empty.

Comment: @Fabian Bigler What if you have ID's 1-10 and you delete ID 8.  So, now you have 1-7 & 9-10.  What happens with this?  I am thinking that MAX would still be 10 so the next ID would still be 11.

Comment: Yes, but IMHO the question is not clear at this point.
" i want to delete id 6 and after add another record but the new record doesn't take that id 6 but it goes to the next id"
=> so I assume he wants to get the NEXT available ID.

Comment: You dont need to get the max value and reseed it. if you just execute the DBCC command without any seed value it will reset the Identity value to next available highest value.

Comment: You answer is correct but I can consider downvoting you just to give OP the answer he can use to do a horrible thing. Also he can just truncate the table. That ill reset the identity.

Comment: @jean I'm here to answer questions, not to debate if it's the best way to do. There have been worse questions like 'how to parse HTML with regex' or heaps of code which is prone to sql injections.
and by the way, my first sentence is: "It's bad practise, but it's possible still." to point out its bad practise

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  That is not how identity columns work.  In fact, the values can have gaps even without deletes.

Instead, do the calculation when you query:

```
select row_number() over (partition by id) as seqnum
```

*You* can maintain such a column if you really want using triggers or similar logic on updates.  Identity does not work this way, because gaps can be caused for other reasons.

Comment: In fact, he can use dbcc checkident to reseed the id.
But it depends on how you understand his question

Comment: down voted. It's a horrible idea to do it but it's possible to reseed. Also truncating the table ill reset the identity

Comment: @jean .. Even reseeding the identity doesn't fix the problem of gaps caused by other reasons.  Reseeding does not guarantee no gaps.  And, you still have to update all the intermediate ids.  Yes, you can do it with a trigger, but then it's not really an identity column.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best thing to do. If you have an Identity field then just let it generate the values for you. If you want to be able to pass values your self then just dont make it an identity value at all.

But if do want to do what you are trying to do then you could do something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees
(
 ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
 NAME varchar (20),
 BALANCE int
)
GO
INSERT INTO new_employees (NAME, BALANCE)
VALUES ('Name 1', 1),('Name 2', 2),('Name 3', 3),
('Name 4', 4),('Name 5', 5)
GO

DELETE FROM new_employees
WHERE ID > 3

DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'new_employees', RESEED,0 )  -<-- with seed value 0
```

> Checking identity information: current identity value '5', current
>   column value '0'.
>  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( 'new_employees', RESEED)   --<-- WIth out any seed value
```

this will reseed the value to highest nest possible Indentity value.

> Checking identity information: current identity value '0', current
>   column value '3'.
>  DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.

```
INSERT INTO new_employees (NAME, BALANCE)
VALUES ('Name 4', 4),('Name 5', 5),('Name 6', 6)
```