# Solution for auto increment reset in mysql

Tags: mysql

While implementing mysql in my project it is found that if we restart mysql service `AUTO_INCREMENT` of that table is reset to value less than the current maximum value in the primary key column.

According to this, suppose one of table having ID (As primary key) up to 100 records and if `DELETE` is performed on 100th ID and restarted mysql service and performed `INSERT` then it will again add new row with ID 100. `INSERT` without restart of mysql service will add 101 ID.(like 1,2,3,4...99,101).

How to avoid this? Means after next restart it must start with 101; Is it possible so?

Comment: might refer to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510121/reset-autoincrement-in-sql-server-after-delete]

Comment: @Deeper , `DBCC` is for SQL server, My question is related to `Mysql`

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No, you should not care about actual id values if your application was designed correctly

Comment: @AlmaDo, How it will be possible?