# SQL Server - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint on INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

When i try to insert into the table with this pk (auto incremental)

```
[foo] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

I get the following error message:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure foobar, Line 39 [Batch Start Line 2]
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_bar'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'table_foo'. The duplicate key value is (9).
The statement has been terminated.

(1 row affected)
```

- we do not try to write into the identity column
- There are around 4mio records in the table, so max pk value is not the issue.
  Another procedure which writes into this table works fine.

Comment: You did not include the insert statement in your question. Please provide an [mcve], see also [ask]

Comment: Please tell us what you would want to know if you were solving this problem.

Comment: Check on what column this key is created, check if the table you are inserting the value of the column on which the key is = 9, check if you are not trying to insert data that try to insert 9 into this column

Comment: Please explain to my how the complete insert statement will help you with this problem, when i specifically stated that we dont insert into the identity column.

Comment: pk is auto incremental

Comment: It's possible that someone has been messing with things they shouldn't have: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This can happen if your identity got reseeded. Check the output of [`DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', NORESEED)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql).

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: Is foo the PK? From your statement, it seems so, though isn't obvious.

Comment: Checking identity information: current identity value '9', current column value '4182913'.
How can this happen and how to fix this? Thank you @JeroenMostert

Comment: It can happen exactly when someone issued a `DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED, <value>)` command when they shouldn't have (or some process did it for them). The fix is simply `DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED)` with no value.

Comment: You're 100% confident that all of these are true?  ***1.*** The PRIMARY KEY is on `table_foo(foo)`?  *(You show the identity column, nothing that evidences that column is also the primary key)*  ***2.*** That you are using `INSERT INTO table_foo (col_x, col_y)`, specifying all the relevant columns, and expressly not specifying column `foo`?  ***3.***  That no-one has reseeded the identity?  ***4.*** That the query you're looking at is really responsible for the `INSERT`?  *(It's not from a trigger, etc?)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824478/

Comment: Please provide the full table structure, the full insert statement (example) and the maximum value which is currently stored in your identity column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510121/

Comment: I said " the table with this pk " and then i post the pk right under it.

Comment: Problem is with reseeding of the table ... if you are lucky and IDs of `1 to 9` never got deleted from table you are fine, just reseed it back to `4182913` and be happy

Comment: And the DDL didn't include the `PRIMARY KEY` key words.  So it ***is*** possible you were mistaken and just assumed that the `IDENTITY` column was also the PK.  People make all sorts of mistakes, asking for clarification on this one helps eliminate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', NORESEED)
```

returned the mismatching values.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED)
```

Fixed it. Thanks @Jeroen Mostert

Comment: Note that "another procedure which writes into this table works fine" is fishy, because this suggests that procedure does use `identity_insert`, and there may be something else (like a scheduled job or other maintenance procedure) that issues `RESEED`s in an attempt to keep identities correct, but which is misfiring. You may want to try a `select [definition] from sys.sql_modules where definition like '%reseed%'`.

Comment: There wont be a reseeding and i either forgot about it or something else must have broken the identity. Either way its fixed and it was the first time it accured so i wont do anything other about it