# INSERT with autoincrement not working in SQL Server (with DB replication ?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

After no row deletion, but after getting the 60 existing rows by local subscription to replication from another SQL Server instance, I'm inserting new rows with:

```
INSERT INTO [Business].[dbo].[ImagesTable] (Filename, Title, Price, PriceString, Category, CategoryRank) 
VALUES ('vegan1.jpg', 'vegan1', 380000, '380,000', 'delices vegan', 0)
```

But this will fail since the `ID` will start over somewhere (9 in this case), instead of starting at the last ID used +1, ie., 61 in my case.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ImagesTable'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ImagesTable'. The duplicate key value is (9).

My table is set to have autoincrement, therefore I should not have to use explicit `IDENT_CURRENT('ImagesTable')`. Why is this happening ?

Furthermore and despite this, when I try to insert explicitly ID I have:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ImagesTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

What is the recommended way to add new rows? How can I insert new rows with the ID being automatically set?

If the presence of DB replication is not propagating the Identity seed, how should I deal with this so I don't have to manage duplicate key errors (I'm certain that I'm not inserting duplicates)?

Comment: Did you had a delete on your records before inserting?

Comment: For the explicit though you can SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON and then insert

Comment: And if theres no deletion performed then how the id will become 61 if autoincrement id has current value as 9. I din get it whats 9 in this case will fail means

Comment: I guess you are inserting duplicates

Comment: Umm.. either way that too wouldve worked as autoincrement would have created new id for those records too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset AutoIncrement in SQL Server after Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510121/reset-autoincrement-in-sql-server-after-delete)

Comment: Can you post theTables complete DDL? Also any triggers too.

Comment: @MarkKram What is DDL ?

Comment: @Soleil, `DDL` is the data definition language subset of the SQL language (e.g. `CREATE TABLE` statements).

Comment: "Merge replication and transactional replication with updating subscriptions use uniqueidentifier columns to guarantee that rows are uniquely identified across multiple copies of the table." [uniqueidentifier (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to segment your `IDENTITY` column ranges in bidirectional replication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/replicate-identity-columns?view=sql-server-ver15